# Simple query for the relationship

Tags: sql, normalization

I need the query for the following ER diagram(It is incomplete, I guess your seniority will help you understand the association well)

Query I need is - list of all employee work phone numbers(type 'W') who work in 'tech' department.

Also, Please let me know if the PK and FK are correctly normalized.

---

Note: For a primary key, i've mentioned **PK** right next to the column name and for a foreign key i used **FK_ (Table Name)**.

---

What I've tried so far

```
select e.emp_id, e.lname from 
Employee e join contactInfo c on e.emp_id = c.emp_id 
join phones p on c.contid = p.cont_id 
join phonetype pt on pt.phoneType_id = p.phoneType_id 
join Department d on d.dept_id = e.dept_id
where dept_id = 'tech' and pt.phoneType_id = 'W'
```

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: `d.Type = 'W' needs to be pt.Type='W'` everything else looks right including normalization.  Assuming an employee cant be in multiple departments and a phone can't be for multiple types (Some people consider mobile and home same) and you don't need history for departments employees have been in.

Comment: Can you add some sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem was in the last line of your querywhere you used "dept_id" and "phoneType_id". Those are probably integer values, not text.  Here's my proposed fix:

```
select e.emp_id, e.lname from 
Employee e join contactInfo c on e.emp_id = c.emp_id 
join phones p on c.contid = p.cont_id 
join phonetype pt on pt.phoneType_id = p.phoneType_id 
join Department d on d.dept_id = e.dept_id
where d.type = 'tech' and pt.type = 'W'
```